# Create a Pop up window where user can choose name when saving file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, popup

I have a code where users can save a txt file. In the function I'm using this.title + 'txt', but by request users want to be able to write/choose a name of the file.
For this I was thinking a Pop up box with an input text field, somewhere inside the function without changing existing html. That's means I just want to do it when calling the function.
Can it be done?

The button in the html page

```
    <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="btn btn-success">Spara insats och odds</button>
```

In download.service.ts

```
    // Specifies JSON download
    downloadJSON() {
      this.download(this.title + '.txt', this.JSON, this.fileText)
    }

    // Specifies XML download
    downloadXML() {
      this.download(this.title + '.xml', this.XML,   this.xmlFile['body']);
    }

    // Creates downloadable link and triggers download
    download(filename, type, text) {
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', type + encodeURIComponent(text));
      element.setAttribute('download', filename);

      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);

      element.click();

      document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) can help you with that.

With: `bootbox.prompt(message, callback)`

With a simple:

```
bootbox.prompt("This is the default prompt!", function(result){ console.log(result); });
```

you can set an input box for the user to fill out the filename intented.

See [Bootbox Prompt Examples](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-prompt-dialog)